# jQuery load data not showing up in page source

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using jQuery for pagination. When the content is loaded into the (#results) div, it shows up on the page but I do not see it in the source code.

I believe this is the cause of issues I am having with CSS and jQuery functions related to that (#results) div. The CSS doesn't see any content in the div so the height doesn't actually cover the content in the div.

```
$("#results").load('pagination.php?page=' + page + ' #results-tbl > *');
```

I'm loading the #results-tbl div from pagination.php into the #results div on the current page.

Is there a better way to be loading this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you viewing the source code? AJAX content won't show in the "View Source" tool of your browser as this only shows the original request source. Use a DOM inspector like Firebug or Chrome's developer tools

Comment: Thanks Ben. That was some copy and paste, only part of the function. just added it back in. Phil, OK. I do see it in Firebug. Then what would explain the CSS issues? Does it not resize to DOM content?

Comment: why don't you paste your code out?

Comment: oh, hi Phil, working hard? :)

Answer (score 1):

Like Phil said,

View source will only show source when the page initially loaded. Any alterations to the DOM / source after this point will not be reflected in normal browser view source.

In addition to browser inspecting tools like Firebug etc, you can use add-ons like web developer add-on.

With the CSS issues, have a look with firebug to see your IDs and classes are actually hooking up to the CSS properties you have in your CSS file. As long as they hook up any new elements added to the DOM should get styled when added.

With height of your parent element, if you don't set its height explicitly, adding any content via AJAX should cause the parent element to stretch vertically to fit its new contents.